# Flex-compile in Flashdevelop can't open .swc

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, swc

I'm currently trying to compile swfs with the flex-SDK using Flashdevelop. I followed the tutorial on [flashdevelop.com](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3%3aFlexAndFlashCS3Workflow), pre-compiled the assets.swc, added it to library, but when i try to build the project i get this error:

> D:-[ DISPLAY ]--[ TechTestLab ]-\Away3D\obj\assetsConfig.xml(28):
>   Error: unable to open 'D:-[ DISPLAY]--[TechTestLab]-\Away3D\src\assets.swc'

Does anyone have an idea to why this is happening?

Comment: Sorry not familiar with FlashDevelop, it appears it's just botching the dependency path you can check if the swc is getting everything included using swfdump.jar located in the bin of the Flex SDK (or through inference checking out the file size and seeing if it seems "appropriate") however it appears this is just a PATH issue of some sort. I do like open source, and Flex ... downloading FD now.  Maybe listing the version of FD may be helpful too.